# package.json with angular2 and express

Tags: express, angular, npm

Hello I just started learning angular 2. I have read a bit on express and have better understanding in that. One thing that confuses me is package.json. particularly the start part.

This is the packege.json when I had only express installed.

```
{
  "name": "Whatever",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.3.3",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Now I decided to install or add angular to the project file. But I am not sure how to properly change package.json.

This is the package.json form angular2 webpage.

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

but this package.json has different start. I am confused on how should the app start now both with angular 2 and express.

**How do I combine both package.json's properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://github.com/CoolHandDev/ng2-express) a GitHub repository that is an example of how to get up and running with the angular release candidate and express.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it says this is not recommended for implementing in production as one exposes node_modules this way. Is there a better or any standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when you need to work on frontend + backend, you will setup 2 projects : **client** and **server**.
Each project will get its own package.json.

**Then you don't need to combine package.json files**.

If you need to get up and running with angular2 and express, you can check [this yeoman generator](https://github.com/ericmdantas/generator-ng-fullstack#readme)

Comment: Where would I put package.json for client? I usually put client files in public, but I'm not sure if that's reasonable for package.json

Comment: If you can serve your client files with another server than the backend, than just create a new project for your client code, with its own package.json. If you want to serve the client files with node and express, than use the same package.json (like in the yeoman generator)

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I'll try that as soon as I get to my laptop :D